# Send a CommanArgument with MouseLeftButtonUp

Tags: silverlight

I would like that my UIElement control acts like a LinkButton in ASP.Net when clicked, and sends an CommandArgument on MouseLeftButtonUp. I suppose I need to make a custom event for this, so I created a OnCommand event like this:

```
public delegate void OnCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e);

public class CommandEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string CommandArgument { get; set; }
}
```

How can I add this event to MouseLeftButtonUp on my UIElement, and also pass the CommandArgument? Or is there another way to accomplish the effect of a LinkButton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt figure out a solution with custom events, so I made a UserControl instead, with a CommandArgument and CommandName properties.

```
   public partial class LinkButton : UserControl
{
    public string CommandArgument { get; set; }
    public string CommandName { get; set; }

    public LinkButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CommandArgument = String.Empty;
        CommandName = String.Empty;
    }

    public void AddElemnent(UIElement obj)
    {
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(obj);
    }
}
```